# Generating a X-2Y chart for the different by length input parameters

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have the date range of start and end dates for X and revenue and transactions for left and right Y axis. The dates for revenue and transactions may not intersect, for example:

```
Start date: 25-Dec-2014
End date: 18-Jul-2015
Revenue-Dates: $15 at 1-Jan-2015, $11 at 8-Jan-2015, $13 at 8-Feb-2015
Transactions-Dates: 3 at 24-Jan-2015, 1 at 28-Jan-2015, 8 at 12-Feb-2015, 2 at 29-May-2015, 4 at 30-May-2015, 3 at 1-Jun-2015
```

I know to how to generate it but only when the amount of the input parameters for all 3 (X and Y,Y) **are the same**, say, 12 month, 12 revenues and 12 transaction for each month.

But given those 4 different by length input parameters, how do I generate a 2-Y-axis chart for it? I want it to begin from Start date and ends by the End date, even so there'r no data at Y for those dates.

**UPDATE**:
In case when I have the same amount of the items in the input parameters:

```
xAxis: [{
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'], //todo
            crosshair: true
        }],
series: [{
            name: 'X1',
            type: 'spline',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4], // toto
        }, {
            name: 'X2',
            type: 'spline',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6], // toto
        }]
```

How can I do that when the amount of items in the input parameters is different?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can just set the min and max of your x axis to the start and end dates.  Then you just build the data series out of whatever points are there for each.

Comment: That being said, plotting two completely different measures with two separate  Y axes is just a plain bad idea.  The better solution is to provide two separate charts, one for each different measure. It provides better usability and eliminates erroneous interpretation.

Comment: @jlbriggs, I'd need to use the "pairs" somehow ({$15: 1-Jan-2015, $11: 8-Jan-2015}), how can I do that? Please look at my update.

Comment: You will need to identify which months do not have data, and populate them with either zero or null values (depending on desired behavior). There are probably a million ways to go about it. You need to define what dates you expect to show data for; loop through that array of dates and finding the data that matches them. If no data matches, insert 0/null instead.

Comment: @jlbriggs, just to clear it up: I need to generate the same chart as at Google Analytics -> Ecommerce. It shows the dates and 2 Y axis which aren't necessarily connected with each other.

Comment: Even when google does it, it's still a bad idea ;) for the record. A good read on why: http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/dual-scaled_axes.pdf

Comment: @jlbriggs, I want to do it initially to see wether it is really.